# Select multiple items that are listed together in Outliner

Tags: objects, selection-tools, outliner, select

How do I select multiple items that are listed together in the Outliner? For example, have a look at the image below: if I want to select from B to G without having to shift-click on everything in between, how do I do that? For example, in Finder on macOS, you can select multiple items that are listed together: click the first item, then press the Shift key and click the last item. All items in between are included in the selection. Is there a way to achieve the same thing in the Outliner?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selection method you describe is now implemented in Blender 2.81, together with Ctrl-left-click selecting (Cmd on a Mac), to toggle between Active and Unselected states for individual items.

<kbd>B</kbd> Box selection is also available, as in the viewport: left-drag to select, middle-drag to deselect.

Comment: Just a note: On mac you can use also natively Cmd instead of Ctrl (for toggling between Active and selecte/deselect individual items).

Comment: @vklidu Oh of course! Thanks.. as you can tell, I'm not a Mac user, I probably should have left this answer to someone who is. Will edit.